# Multiple Selection on ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In my application, I show some data to the user depending on which category he chooses. For that, I'm using ActionBarSherlock, to display a menu of categories he can choose from. When one category is clicked, this content is loaded. What I now want to do is enable a multi-select option, with checkboxes, and an OK button to trigger the content loading. I've been searching for some time and couldn't figure out how to enable this multi-select menu. Below is part of my current code

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends SherlockActivity implements
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(Application.THEME);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_ringtones);

        Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();

        categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

        ArrayAdapter<Category> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(context,
            R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, categoryList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search);

        // By default, load data for the first category
        loadCategoryData(categoryList.get(0).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

            loadCategoryData(categoryList.get(itemPosition).getId());
            return false;
    }
```